# compute date feature from two feature in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop

Hello I'd like to compute a new feature `duration` from `date_start` and `date_end`. If the contract not yet ended I compute it using today date. My problem is it's been 1hours my for loop is running I've only 200K rows. 
What's wrong (maybe) with my code?  Is there another way to do this more simple?

```
dftopyear['duration'] = ''
for x in dftopyear.Date_resil:
    if x == pd.isnull(np.datetime64('NaT')): # this mean contract not yet ended
        dftopyear['duration'] = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") - dftopyear['date_start'] 
    else: # this mean contact ended 
        dftopyear['duration'] = dftopyear['Date_end'] - dftopyear['date_start']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a major problem here is, when you do the minus dftopyear['date_start'], it's doing minus against the entire DataFrame.

You need a index locator to point to a single value, rather than an entire series:

```py
dftopyear['duration'] = ''
for i,x in enumerate(dftopyear.Date_resil):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        dftopyear.iloc[i, 'duration'] = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") - dftopyear.iloc[i, 'date_start'] 
    else: 
        dftopyear.iloc[i, 'duration'] = dftopyear.iloc[i, 'Date_end'] - dftopyear.iloc[i, 'date_start']
```

or a more pythonic way:

```py
dftopyear['duration'] = ''
for i,x in enumerate(dftopyear.Date_resil):
    end_day = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if pd.isnull(x) else dftopyear.iloc[i, 'Date_end']
    dftopyear.iloc[i, 'duration'] = end_day - dftopyear.iloc[i, 'date_start']
```

Comment: Thanks let try it. mine finish running with entry NaT values.

Comment: i've got this error

`ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types`

Comment: my columns are in datetime fomat.

Comment: did you use the enumerate(dftopyear.Date_resil) function in for loop? you will get an integer i as index to be referred to your DataFrame as an locator.

Comment: Yes I did even the first one i is integer

Comment: try use my updated answer. I think the first publish has a typo was corrected later.

Comment: there's a tiny change on the last line. Before, there's a dftopyear[i, 'date_start'], which is highly likely what's causing your exceptions. it should be dftopyear.iloc[i, 'date_start']

Comment: I see the problem and fixe it now, iloc take only integer I replaced the var name by its index in axis 1.
THANKS

Comment: for complement `pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) ` we need also convert it to datetime.

Comment: You are right. It's actually only dt.datetime.today() is needed if your date column is already datetime. I'll update in the answer.